# Automating xterm using Expect

Tags: tcl, expect, xterm

I am trying to automate `xterm` window using `Expect` (though I already knew `Expect` cant control such GUI applications, but there is a tweaked mechanism explained in [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do))

```
package require Expect 
spawn -pty
stty raw -echo < $spawn_out(slave,name)
regexp ".*(.)(.)" $spawn_out(slave,name) dummy c1 c2
if {[string compare $c1 "/"] == 0} {
    set c1 "0"
}
set xterm_pid [exec xterm -S$c1$c2$spawn_out(slave,fd) &]
close -slave
expect "\n" ;# match and discard X window id

set xterm $spawn_id 

spawn $env(SHELL)
```

Don Libes mentioned that from this point, xterm can be automated and he has given example to use xterm with `interact` command as follows,

```
interact -u $xterm "X" {
    send -i $xterm "Press return to go away: "
    set timeout -1
    expect -i $xterm "\r" {
        send -i $xterm "Thanks!\r\n"
        exec kill $xterm_pid
        exit
    }
}
```

But, my expectation is send and expect commands to/from xterm. I have tried the following,

```
send -i $xterm "ls -l\r"; # Prints commands on xterm 
expect -i $xterm "\\\$" ; # Trying to match the prompt
```

But it didn't workout. This example mainly relies on the xterm's command line option `-Sccn`.

**-Sccn**

> This option allows xterm to be used as an input and output channel for
>   an existing program and is sometimes used in specialized applications.
>   The option value specifies the last few letters of the name of a
>   pseudo-terminal to use in slave mode, plus the number of the inherited
>   file descriptor. If the option contains a "/" character, that delimits
>   the characters used for the pseudo-terminal name from the file
>   descriptor. Otherwise, exactly two characters are used from the option
>   for the pseudo-terminal name, the remainder is the file descriptor.
>   Examples:

```
-S123/45
-Sab34
```

> Note that xterm does not close any file descriptor which it did not open for its own use. It is possible (though probably not
>   portable) to have an application which passes an open file descriptor
>   down to xterm past the initialization or the -S option to a process
>   running in the xterm.

Where am I making the mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mr.Thomas Dickey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518274/thomas-dickey) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883507/974155), I started exploring on the [multixterm](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html)
and finally able to make a standalone version where the commands are sent to `xterm` directly.

The part which mainly I have missed in my code is `expect_background` which actually does the linking in the background.  Hope it helps to all those who all wanted to automate the `xterm`. All credits to Mr.Thomas Dickey and Mr.Don Libes!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
package require Expect
set ::xtermStarted 0
set xtermCmd      $env(SHELL)
set xtermArgs     ""

# set up verbose mechanism early
set verbose 0
proc verbose {msg} {
    if {$::verbose} {
    if {[info level] > 1} {
        set proc [lindex [info level -1] 0]
    } else {
        set proc main
    }
        puts "$proc: $msg"
    }
}
# ::xtermSid is an array of xterm spawn ids indexed by process spawn ids.
# ::xtermPid is an array of xterm pids indexed by process spawn id.

######################################################################
# create an xterm and establish connections
######################################################################

proc xtermStart {cmd name} {
    verbose "starting new xterm running $cmd with name $name"
    ######################################################################
    # create pty for xterm
    ######################################################################
    set pid [spawn -noecho -pty]
    verbose "spawn -pty: pid = $pid, spawn_id = $spawn_id"
    set ::sidXterm $spawn_id
    stty raw -echo < $spawn_out(slave,name)
    regexp ".*(.)(.)" $spawn_out(slave,name) dummy c1 c2
    if {[string compare $c1 "/"] == 0} {
        set c1 0
    }
    ######################################################################
    # start new xterm
    ######################################################################
    set xtermpid [eval exec xterm -name dinesh -S$c1$c2$spawn_out(slave,fd) $::xtermArgs &]
    verbose "xterm: pid = $xtermpid"
    close -slave

    # xterm first sends back window id, save in environment so it can be
    # passed on to the new process
    log_user 0
    expect {
        eof {wait;return}
        -re (.*)\n {
            # convert hex to decimal
            # note quotes must be used here to avoid diagnostic from expr
            set ::env(WINDOWID) [expr "0x$expect_out(1,string)"]
        }
    }

    ######################################################################
    # start new process
    ######################################################################
    set pid [eval spawn -noecho $cmd]
    verbose "$cmd: pid = $pid, spawn_id = $spawn_id"
    set ::sidCmd $spawn_id

    ######################################################################
    # link everything back to spawn id of new process
    ######################################################################
   set ::xtermSid($::sidCmd) $::sidXterm
   set ::xtermPid($::sidCmd) $xtermpid

    ######################################################################
    # connect proc output to xterm output
    # connect xterm input to proc input
    ######################################################################
    expect_background {
        -i $::sidCmd
        -re ".+" {
            if {!$::xtermStarted} {set ::xtermStarted 1}
            sendTo $::sidXterm
        }
        eof [list xtermKill $::sidCmd]
        -i $::sidXterm
        -re ".+" {
            if {!$::xtermStarted} {set ::xtermStarted 1}
            sendTo $::sidCmd
        }
        eof [list xtermKill $::sidCmd]
    }
    vwait ::xtermStarted
}


######################################################################
# connect main window keystrokes to all xterms
######################################################################
proc xtermSend {A} {
    exp_send -raw -i $::sidCmd -- $A
}

proc sendTo {to} {
    exp_send -raw -i $to -- $::expect_out(buffer)
}


######################################################################
# clean up an individual process death or xterm death
######################################################################
proc xtermKill {s} {
    verbose "killing xterm $s"

    if {![info exists ::xtermPid($s)]} {
        verbose "too late, already dead"
        return
    }

    catch {exec /bin/kill -9 $::xtermPid($s)}
    unset ::xtermPid($s)

    # remove sid from activeList
    verbose "removing $s from active array"
    catch {unset ::activeArray($s)}

    verbose "removing from background handler $s"
    catch {expect_background -i $s}
    verbose "removing from background handler $::xtermSid($s)"
    catch {expect_background -i $::xtermSid($s)}
    verbose "closing proc"
    catch {close -i $s}
    verbose "closing xterm"
    catch {close -i $::xtermSid($s)}
    verbose "waiting on proc"
    wait -i $s
    wait -i $::xtermSid($s)
    verbose "done waiting"
    unset ::xtermSid($s)
    set ::forever NO
}

######################################################################
# create windows
######################################################################
# xtermKillAll is not intended to be user-callable.  It just kills
# the processes and that's it. A user-callable version would update
# the data structures, close the channels, etc.

proc xtermKillAll {} {
    foreach sid [array names ::xtermPid] {
        exec /bin/kill -9 $::xtermPid($sid)
    }
}

rename exit _exit
proc exit {{x 0}} {xtermKillAll;_exit $x}


xtermStart $xtermCmd $xtermCmd
xtermSend "ls -l\r"
xtermSend "pwd\r"
vwait ::forever
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have you a view from my code I used. It is extracted from a complex part.

```
# create pty for xterm
set spawn(PTTY,PID) [spawn -noecho -pty]
set spawn(PTTY,DEVICE) $spawn_out(slave,name)
set spawn(PTTY) $spawn_id
stty raw -echo < $spawn(PTTY,DEVICE)
regexp ".*(.)(.)" $spawn_out(slave,name) dummy c1 c2
if {[string compare $c1 "/"] == 0} { set c1 0 }

# Start XTERM (using -into can place the xterm in a TK widget)
set pid(XTERM) [::exec xterm   -S$c1$c2$spawn_out(slave,fd) {*}$addidtionlXtermOptions  &]
close -slave

# Link
set spawn(SHELL,PID)    [spawn -noecho {*}$commandInXterm]
set spawn(SHELL)        $spawn_id
set spawn(SHELL,DEVICE) $spawn_out(slave,name)

# ...
# send a key or string into the xterm
exp_send -raw -i $spawn(SHELL) --  $key
exp_send -raw -i $spawn(SHELL) -- "$str\r
```

Comment: If we start `bash` in `xterm` and your `spawn(SHELL)` will contain the spawned bash's `spawn_id`.  Sending commands to `spawn(SHELL)` will eventually send/expect commands to/from the spawned bash process. It looks like we are spawning separate bash and just printing the output in `xterm` window.